# How to unilaterally synchronize two database schemas in PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, pgadmin

I have two databases with the names A and B.

- B is a copied database by using the schema of database A.
- Currently, whenever a change in database A's schema happens, database B doesn't automatically get updated.
- I would like to design a synchronization between the schemas of databases A and B, in a way that, whenever a change happens in the schema of A, database B's schema will also get updated.
- However, if the schema of B changes, schema of A will not get updated. So the synchronization should be unilateral.

How can I handle these requirements in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0):

That is a classical application for [logical replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication.html).

Be sure to perform no data modifications on database B that conflict with operations replicated from A, since that will cause logical replication to get stuck, and you will have to fix it manually.

Also note that DDL changes and sequence manipulations won't be replicated, at least not in v14.